# How to implement "substringAfter" in one line?

Tags: string, scala

I want to find an one-line function to implement `substringAfter` in scala, which is the same as commons-lang's `StringUtils.substringAfter()`.

```
def substringAfter(str:String, key:String) = ...
```

Some tests:

```
substringAfter("1234512345", "23") // ==> 4512345
substringAfter("1234512345", "a") // ==> ""
substringAfter("1234512345", "")  // ==> 1234512345
substringAfter("", "23") // ==> ""
```

No need to consider `null` str here.

For now, I have such a solution:

```
def substringAfter(s:String,k:String) = {
  s.indexOf(k) match {
    case -1 => ""
    case i => s.substring(i+k.length)
  }
}
```

How to get an one-line one?

Comment: At least to my eyes that's quite simple already.

Comment: You have your function definition.  You See if the string is inside using 1 line. If it is you return what you want in 1 line if it isn't you return something else in 1 line.  
I'm with Niklas B I don't see how much simpler you want it to be?

Comment: @Jordan, maybe I want an one-line function, I just updated the question.

Comment: @Freewind: See what you have done? Now someone simply collapsed that already very simple function onto one line, making it a very unreadable mess :) You can't blame him/her!

Comment: This is true.  I'm innocent.  Truly could anyone help themselves??
@NiklasB. damn English for not having a neuter gender. I'm a he anyway.

Comment: Ermmm... Just import commons-lang. Scala isn't about reinventing the wheel!

Answer (score 5):

```
def substringAfter(s:String,k:String) = { s.indexOf(k) match { case -1 => ""; case i => s.substring(i+k.length)  } }
```

Comment: It is possible to leave the semicolon between two case-statements.

Answer (score 4):

Less efficient, but slightly shorter:

```
def substringAfter(s: String, k: String) =
  s.tails.find(_.startsWith(k)).map(_.drop(k.length)).getOrElse("")
```

or if regexes are your thing:

```
def substringAfter(s: String, k: String) = 
  (".*?(?:\Q"+k+"\E)(.*)").r.unapplySeq(s).flatten.mkString
```

Comment: Yes, I'd enclose raw text with \Q and \E.

Comment: That won't work if the string contains an `\E` itself, but it certainly helps.  I had numeric strings on the mind before (where it doesn't matter).

Answer (score 1):

My friend gave me a solution:

```
def substringAfter(str:String, key:String) =
   str.stripPrefix(str.take(str.indexOf(key))+key)
```

Comment: The second doesn't work, e.g. `substringAfter("1234567", "29")`

Comment: You realize the only reason this is on one line is you are chaining the outputs.  If you were assigning the outputs to individual variables it would NOT be shorter.  IE it looks shorter but operationally it isn't.

Comment: In fact, it's actually much less readable as the original version, in my opinion

Answer (score 1):

Your version rewritten to use a Map with default function:

```
def substringAfter(s: String, k: String) = 
  Map(-1 -> "").withDefault(i => s.substring(i + k.length))(s.indexOf(k))
```